# The series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $a_n,b_n,c_n$ be sequences of positive numbers that satisfy $\sum b_n<\infty$, $c_n\rightarrow c\ge 0$ and
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k+c_n\text{ for all }n\in \mathbb{N}.$$
Can we get that $a_n\rightarrow 0?$ It is clear that if $\{a_n\}$ is bounded, the inequality above gives us $a_n\rightarrow 0$. But I do not know how to proceed when $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t_n$ be the sum on the left. By Cauhcy-Schwarz inequlity we get $t_n \leq \sqrt {t_n} B+C$ for some finite constants $B$ and $C$. [I am using the fact that $\sum b_n^{2} <\infty$ which follows from the fact that $\sum b_n <\infty$].

Now $(\sqrt t_n-\frac 1  2 B)^{2}=t_n-B \sqrt {t_n}+\frac  1  4 B^{2}$ is bounded and hence $t_n$ is bounded. It follows that $\sum a_n^{2} <\infty$, so $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!